# how to filter few rows in a table using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Using Scala:
I have a emp table as below

```
id, name,   dept,   address
1,  a,  10, hyd
2,  b,  10, blr
3,  a,  5,  chn
4,  d,  2,  hyd
5,  a,  3,  blr
6,  b,  2,  hyd
```

Code:

```scala
val inputFile = sc.textFile("hdfs:/user/edu/emp.txt"); 
val inputRdd = inputFile.map(iLine => (iLine.split(",")(0),
                             iLine.split(",")(1), 
                             iLine.split(",")(3)
                            )); 
// filtering only few columns Now i want to pull hyd addressed employees complete data
```

**Problem:** I don't want to print all emp details, I want to print only few emp details who all are from hyd.

1. I have loaded this emp dataset into Rdd
2. I was split this Rdd with ','
3. now I want to print only hyd addressed emp.

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: val  inputFile = sc.textFile("hdfs:/user/edu/emp.txt");

val inputRdd = inputFile.map(iLine => (iLine.split(",")(0),iLine.split(",")(1), iLine.split(",")(3))); // filterin only few columns

Now i want to pull hyd addressed employees complete data

Comment: Did you try filter method on a RDD ?

Comment: pls share the code to filter  rows on rdd

Answer (score 0):

I think the below solution will help to solve your problem.

```
  val fileName = "/path/stact_test.txt"
  val strRdd = sc.textFile(fileName).map { line =>
    val data = line.split(",")
    (data(0), data(1), data(3))
  }.filter(rec=>rec._3.toLowerCase.trim.equals("hyd"))
```

after splitting the data, filter the location using the 3rd item from the tuple RDD.

Output:

```
(1,  a, hyd)
(4,  d,  hyd)
(6,  b,  hyd)
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try to use dataframe

```scala
val viewsDF=spark.read.text("hdfs:/user/edu/emp.txt")
val splitedViewsDF = viewsDF.withColumn("id", split($"value",",").getItem(0))
                            .withColumn("name", split($"value", ",").getItem(1))
                            .withColumn("address", split($"value", ",").getItem(3))
                            .drop($"value")
                            .filter(df("address").equals("hyd") )
```

Comment: thnx but, I'm getting error: <console>:25: error: overloaded method value filter with alternatives:
  (func: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FilterFunction[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (func: org.apache.spark.sql.Row => Boolean)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (conditionExpr: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] <and>
  (condition: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 cannot be applied to (Boolean)

Comment: try df("address").equals("hyd")